# How to use id of a document as a key of an array in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have 2 collections:

1. user collection
2. group collection

user collection:

```
[
    
    {
        "_id" : "ofZq8B4bLKj7HD5y7",
        "groups" : [cqJdqamzn7c2ZkQB5,7STwxmi7jgQQo7Zpc,b575zYtTCjLiJHS2c],
        "profile" : {
            "firstname" : "user-000010",
            "lastname" : "la"
        }
    },

    {
        "_id" : "N6QWtnvBDZjWtLPwL",
        "groups" : [cqJdqamzn7c2ZkQB5,b575zYtTCjLiJHS2c],
        "profile" : {
            "firstname" : "user-000012",
            "lastname" : "sa"
        }
    },

    {
        "_id" : "ayghwXCnE8Txy6awL",
        "groups" : [cqJdqamzn7c2ZkQB5,7STwxmi7jgQQo7Zpc],
        "profile" : {
            "firstname" : "user-000066",
            "lastname" : "wq"
        }
    }   
]
```

Group Collection:

```
[

    {
        "_id" : "cqJdqamzn7c2ZkQB5",
        "name" : "testgroup1",
        "description" : "test user group1"
    },

    {
        "_id" : "7STwxmi7jgQQo7Zpc",
        "name" : "testgroup2",
        "description" : "test user group2"
    },
    {
        "_id" : "b575zYtTCjLiJHS2c",
        "name" : "testgroup3",
        "description" : "test user group3"
    }
]
```

I want to get the count of the users for every group.

for e.g:
for group_id "cqJdqamzn7c2ZkQB5" the user count is 3, for group_id "7STwxmi7jgQQo7Zpc" and "b575zYtTCjLiJHS2c" the count is 2.

I have tried to use lookup and have joined 2 tables for getting the count but for very large data set it is failing. Below is the code snippet what i have tried:

```
const aggQuery = [

        {

            "$project" : {
                "_id" : 1,
                "name" : 1,
                "description" : 1,
            }

        }
    ];

    let groups = await Groups.aggregate(aggQuery);

    let groupIds =  groups.map(elem => {

          return elem._id

    })

    const userAggQuery = [

        {

           "$unwind":"$groups"

        },

        {

           "$match":{

              "groups":{

                 "$in": groupIds

              }

           }

        },

        {

           "$group":{

              "_id":"$groups",

              "users":{

                 "$sum":1

              }

           }

        }

     ];

     let users = await Users.aggregate(userAggQuery);

     for (let i = 0; i < groups.length; i++) {

        for (let j = 0; j < users.length; i++) {

            if (groups[i]._id == users[j]._id) {

                groups[i].users = users[j]["users"]

            }

        }

    }

    return groups;
```

I want the result from the query in a specific way. Kindly help me out to achieve this.

```
[
    
    {
        "cqJdqamzn7c2ZkQB5" : {
            userCount:3,
            name : "testgroup1",
            description : "test user group1"
        }
    },

    {
        "7STwxmi7jgQQo7Zpc" : {
            userCount:3,
            name : "testgroup2",
            description : "test user group2"
        }
    },

    {
        "b575zYtTCjLiJHS2c" : {
            userCount:3,
            name : "testgroup3",
            description : "test user group3"
        }
    }
]
```

Does anyone have any idea?